# Load external content using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to load an external site's content using jQuery's Ajax rather than an iFrame?

This is what I am trying to achieve, but it would seem there might be some cross domain issues with this?

```
$('#result').load('http://www.google.com');
```

In flash you can put a cross-domain policy file in the root of the site allow certain sites to access the content of swf files or other files. Is this something that could be done using AJAX?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Possibly a stupid question here, you want an `<iframe>` behavior, why *not* use an `<iframe>`?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, in part. You'll need to have your server act as a proxy:

```
$('#result').load('fetch.php?s=http://www.google.com');
// or something like that
```

As for having the client load a page cross-domain, it won't (shouldn't) be possible.

Comment: The contents of fetch.php being: `echo file_get_contents($_GET['s']);` for example.

Comment: You'd probably want some validation on that input - imagine if somebody called that with s=/etc/password...

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to load an external site's content using jQuery's Ajax rather than an iFrame?

The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) usually prevents it. You can work around it using [JSON-P](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonp-json-with-padding) to transport that data.

> In flash you can put a cross-domain policy file in the root of the site allow certain sites to access the content of swf files or other files. Is this something that could be done using AJAX?

Not cross-browser, the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) is too new (and unfinished)