# cross domain ajax call

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, xss

i tried to make an cross domain ajax call with native javascript and it works with out any jsonp techniques, i am wondering how it is  possible . i read that cross domain ajax calls cannot be made due to security risk

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">



function loadXMLDoc()
{
url=document.getElementById('url_data').value;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<input type"text" id="url_data" value="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20flickr.photos.info%20where%20photo_id%3D'2186714153'&format=json"/>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

can some one help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load external content using AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157592/load-external-content-using-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

The site has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header, which allows cross-origin requests from any(`*`) site.

This makes the server ignore the security risk and send the response. However, i suggest you use a script tag and callback instead of xhr to request the data, which is the standard method to requesting JSONP (ie. jQuery's `$.getJSON` function). It is much more reliable.

Comment: how can you see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?  I tried displaying xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders() in a separate div and all I got was `Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8 Cache-Control: no-cache, private`

Comment: If you use the Network Monitor of Firefox you can effectively see that the header contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Answer (score 0):

May be these lines of code solve your problem which is for regular web service created in asp .net & call using ajax

```
          var jsonData = [YOUR JSON PARAMETER];

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: [YOUR WEB SERVICE URL],
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                  
                data: JSON.stringify({ json: jsonData }),
                dataType: "json",                
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function(err) {
                    alert("Error : " + err.d);
                }  
            }); 

            function OnSuccess(data) {
                alert("Success:" + data.d);                       
            }
```

You can do one thing for that just need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin & Access-Control-Allow-Headers in CustomeHeaders your web service web.config file.

```
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```

If you want to allow only for specific domain , you can do that with specific value of domain instead of * value