# Multiple JQuery load() events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load external content using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157592/load-external-content-using-ajax)

I'm very new to the JQuery programming and trying to load different webpages into seperate divs, but i cant seem to get it to work, what am i doing wrong?

here is the page loading per div id

```
$(function(){

   $('#google').load('https://www.google.nl/');
   $('#bing').load('http://www.bing.com/');
});
```

and the rest of the code for showing multiple pages:

```
<div data-role="page" id="main"> 

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> 
        <h1>Search</h1> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   
        <h2>define your choice</h2>       
        <p>Go to: <a href="#google">google</a></p> 
        <p>Go to: <a href="#bing">bing</a></p> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"> 
        <h4>Footer</h4> 
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Start of second page --> 
<div data-role="page" id="GameFart" data-add-back-btn="true"> 

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> 
        <h1>google</h1> 
    </div> 

    <div data-role="content">   
 <div id="google">
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"> 
        <h4>Footer</h4> 
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Start of third page --> 
<div data-role="page" id="GameSpecials" data-add-back-btn="true"> 

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> 
        <h1>bing</h1> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   
 <div id="bing">
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"> 
        <h4>Footer</h4> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's simply not possible to access external domains with Ajax unless they allow it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. Google and Bing certainly don't like their sites being embedded in other sites (if you can call that embedding).

Comment: What felix said, and Google uses the [X-frame options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header), so you can't really frame it or get the content with client side scripting.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `.load()` uses AJAX and AJAX is restricted by the browser according to the same origin policies that you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

That means you can't freely load the content of other web sites at different domains into your page.

You can embed some sites using an iframe (the browser will allow that), but a particular site may prevent you putting them in an iframe (like Google).

Comment: the originial code is different, as i didn't want to share my urls directly, i will use the oldskool iframe then. thank you very much for the help :-)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not your code. It is rather the policy of certain websites, including Bing and Google.

In regular HTML you can't make a Frame that displays Google, for Google doesn't allow it. Same with AJAX. And @FelixKling is correct.